# Twig: How to unescape "&amp;"?

Tags: url, twig

I'm facing an issue. I want to generate an url with several parameters.

Method used

```
{{ url('example', {'product_filter_form': {'parameter_one': ['montres'], 'parameter_two': ['value2']}}) }}
```

Expected Url:

> `https://example.com?product_filter_form%5Bparameter_one%5D%5B0%5D=value1`**&**`product_filter_form%5Bparameter_two%5D%5B0%5D=value2`

Unescaped expected url:

> `https://example.com?product_filter_form[parameter_one][]=value1`**&**`product_filter_form[parameter_two][]=value2`

Actual Url:

> `https://example.com?product_filter_form%5Bparameter_one%5D%5B0%5D=value1`**&amp**;`product_filter_form%5Bparameter_two%5D%5B0%5D=value2`

The `&amp;` breaks the url behaviour and i can't extract all values. But when I replace  `&amp;` by `&` it works very well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `&` character is being automatically HTML-escaped to `&amp;` by twig.

Use the `raw` filter to prevent this default behavior (i.e. for rendering a URI inside an HTML attribute).

```
<a href="{{ '<uri>' | raw }}">
  Link
</a>
```